# Stored Procedure Error in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cakephp

I am using cakephp to call a stored procedure like this:

```
$results = $this->query('call p2');
echo $results;
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered 
queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code 
is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the 
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

My stored procedure is as follows (an works in MySQL):

```
DELIMITER //  

CREATE PROCEDURE `p2` ()  
LANGUAGE SQL  
DETERMINISTIC  
SQL SECURITY DEFINER  
COMMENT 'A procedure'  
BEGIN  
    SELECT 'Hello World !';  
END//
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think you have some problem in calling procedure from `cakephp` and not in `MySQL`.

Comment: see this may help you: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10360219-RESOLVED-PDO-quot-Cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries-are-active-quot

Comment: its definitely some cakephp problem